# button outside the scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, scrollview

I have set my scrollView only on a part of the screen.

```
    UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)];
    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,1500);//568    
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Also, out of the scrollView I have set a button.

```
    UIButton *hintbtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,self.view.frame.size.height - 50,160,50)];
    [hintbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(hint:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:hintbtn];
```

If you press this button, I want to make the scrollView to scroll down.

```
    -(void)hintbtn:(UIButton*)button {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50) animated:YES];
    }
```

However, it gives an error saying "unknown receiver 'scrollView'". Is there a way to fox this?
Please help me, how to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because you don't have a reference to your `scrollview` variable. To fix the issue please do the following:

In your class' header file (The *.h file) add the following:

```
@interface YOUR_CLASS_NAME : UIViewController

// Add the following line to the header file
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

Then, in the implementation file (The *.m file) add the following:

```
// Wherever you have this code. It's probably in 'viewDidLoad'
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)];
self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,1500);//568 
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

// In the following line you have a typo. The selector should be "hintbtn:"!
[hintbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(hintbtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Also modify this code:
-(void)hintbtn:(UIButton*)button {
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50) animated:YES];
}
```

Let me know if you have more questions.

Hope this helps!